# Auto scaling group with mixed instances only deploys one instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to get my EC2 auto-scaling group to deploy two separate instances based on the load of an ECS cluster. My auto-scaling group is setup so that it contains multiple instances with varying weights (associated with number of tasks that each instance can handle). However, when I launch tasks within ECS, the auto scaling group only appears to launch the first instance type and doesn't launch the latter.

Here is the auto-scaling group:
[image: Auto scaling group with mixed instances]

And here is the instance page that shows 3 of the smaller instances were launched and none of the larger.
[image: Smaller instances running]

What I was expecting to happen was first a smaller instance would be launched and then a larger instance would be launched.

Comment: Happens to me too, even when new tasks are executed with placement-constraints specifying the larger type. Did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: I have a hunch that AWS doesn't give a proper error message: when I removed the weaker type from the ASG, I got a message that the stronger one was not available in the availability zone. So if you see that kind of behavior, maybe try a different zone?

Comment: I didn't end up solving this issue, I ended up just going with all the same instance types.